# How to integrate $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x^{-p})}{x^2}dx$ where $p>1$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, gamma-function

How to integrate the following integral:

$$\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin(x^{-p})}{x^2} dx, p>1 ?$$

**Thank you for any help.**

**Attempt:** I have tried simple sub: $x^{-p} =u \implies du=dx (-p)x^{-p-1}.$

$$\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin(x^{-p})}{x^2} dx = \dfrac{-1}{p}\int_{\infty}^{0} \sin(u)x^{p-1}du .$$

However, I can not proceed further with this sub.

Comment: Have you tried change of variables?

Comment: With CAS: $-\frac{\pi  \sec \left(\frac{\pi }{2 p}\right)}{2 \Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{p}\right)}$

Comment: @Jack Yes, but got nothing I could work with.

Comment: @Thom: If you type out those work in the post, people would not close your question. (There have been four close votes so far.)

Comment: I see you put the `complex-analysis` and `contour-integration` tags under the post. Are you specifically looking for methods in complex analysis?

Comment: @Jack Yea, that would be good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the change of variable $u=x^{-p}$, the integral becomes
$$
\frac{1}{p}\int_{0}^\infty \sin(u)u^{1/p-1}du=\frac{1}{p}\mathcal{M}\{\sin(u)\}(1/p),
$$
where $\mathcal{M}$ denotes the Mellin transform.

Since $0<1/p<1$, one can easily infer from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MellinTransform.html
that
$$
\frac{1}{p}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2p}\right)=\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{p}+1\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2p}\right)
$$
is the value of the aforementioned integral.